# How to show text over the text box background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've setup a kind of autocomplete & editable dropdown using regular textbox and a background dropdown icon to be shown right inside of the textbox using textbox css background-image. It solves my problem.

```
    background-image: url('/Content/Images/DropdownCustom.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The problem here is that the text in text box overlaps on the background image when it is longer. Is there any way I can bring the background image and show on top of the text as like as the regular dropdown is shown.

EDIT:

The solution proposed by Pete is working in Chrome, not in IE 8. Is it possible to do in IE? Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b72jeqjx/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add right padding to your textbox so the text can't go into that area

Comment: Can you please share with us a Fiddle demo of your issue?

Comment: The "background" part of "background-image" should be a pretty strong clue here. No, you can't bring it over the text, because then it would be "foreground".

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your answer. It works really well in Chrome, not in IE8. Do you have any tricks for IE 8

Comment: @DanielSanchez http://jsfiddle.net/b72jeqjx/1/